# DirectX-XAML interop: DXGI_ERROR_DRIVER_INTERNAL_ERROR

Tags: xaml, directx, uwp

I am following [official Direct X and XAML interop tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh825871.aspx) on Direct X - XAML interop in Windows Store app using [VirtualSurfaceImageSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.virtualsurfaceimagesource.aspx). The problem I am encountering here is that when the app is resumed after being suspended for inactivity, the rendering area blacks out. Chasing the problem in Visual Studio reveals that it fails at the line

```c
HRESULT beginDrawHR = m_vsisNative->BeginDraw(updateRect, &bigSurface, &offset);
```

as in the tutorial. The HRESULT message says that

**The GPU device instance has been suspended. Use GetDeviceRemovedReason to determine the appropriate action.**

Doing what it says i.e. calling `GetDeviceRemovedReason`, I get `DXGI_ERROR_DRIVER_INTERNAL_ERROR` as the reason the device is removed which I have no idea to resolve. For the original `HRESULT`, I think the reason for GPU instance to be suspended is due to `Trim`ing of 3D device when the app is about to suspend (otherwise, the app will NOT pass certification). When it resumes, somehow the GPU instance does not get resumed. Hence, the drawing code never executes after resuming as `BeginDraw` never succeed, resulting in a black canvas. Removing the trimming code, it renders the content perfectly when resuming app but after a while, I get NULL pointer access for common resources such as brushes created using `CreateSolidColorBrush`.

Unfortunately, there is no hint how to handle the device removed in the tutorial:

```c
HRESULT beginDrawHR = m_vsisNative->BeginDraw(updateRect, &bigSurface, &offset);
if (beginDrawHR == DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_REMOVED || beginDrawHR == DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_RESET)
{
    // device changed
}
else
{
    // draw to IDXGISurface
}
```

How should I resolve the error?

Answer (score 0):

I have download the [VirtualSurfaceImageSource sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.virtualsurfaceimagesource.aspx) which I supposed is the one you are following. And I resumed the app lots of times and on different time intervals. However, I couldn't reproduce your problem. So could you please prepare a more detailed sample code to help us to reproduce the problem? And I also have several questions: Have you tried your program on other computers? Can you successfully run the original MSDN sample? Can you resume other DX programs successfully?

Actually, when we are using VirtualSurfaceImageSource, no extra operation required on resume as the application is only visually updated. This is clearly stated in the sample program(App::OnResuming). The application's activation logic will ensure that the application saved state is properly restored. Maybe you'd better firstly cross check the device initial process in your program with the sample file.

Per my understanding, the resuming issue you are facing may be more likely related with the graphic driver. When after trimming it couldn't be reload properly. Which kind of display card you are using? Could you go to its website for the latest update?

And currently, a workaround for your program may be to double check the device connecting status when resuming. But this may need tons of codes to maintain the application status after reconnecting.

Let me know if you have any update.